# barplotting a list of numbers in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

Im totally new to R, im working on some scripts for plotting some cheap barplot charts for my thesis.

I have a file with portnumbers, one by line:

```
115
220
192
196
1433
115
220
192
196
1433
115
220
192
196
1433
115
220
192
196
1433
```

now i want to plot this in a barplot
.
X-Axis: Occurences
Y-Axis: Portnumber

Here is my not working script. It would work, if the Numbers wouldn't be interpreted as Strings, i suppose, because it works with strings. How do i fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

#barplot
dat=read.table("data/ports.txt", header=FALSE)
plot(dat, col=c("#ccf0fe9f"),horiz=TRUE,cex.names=0.5,las=1,width=5, xlab='Attacks')
```

when executing i get some very unrelated warnings.. so unrelated, i think it's of no use posting them in here.

thanks in advance for any hints & help!

EDIT: here are the warnings(sadly in german):

```
f00@localhost R$ ./ports.r 
There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Warnmeldungen:
1: In plot.window(...) : "horiz" ist kein Grafikparameter
2: In plot.window(...) : "cex.names" ist kein Grafikparameter
3: In plot.window(...) : "width" ist kein Grafikparameter
4: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "horiz" ist kein Grafikparameter
5: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "cex.names" ist kein Grafikparameter
6: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "width" ist kein Grafikparameter
7: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "horiz" ist kein Grafikparameter
8: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "cex.names" ist kein Grafikparameter
9: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "width" ist kein Grafikparameter
10: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "horiz" ist kein Grafikparameter
11: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "cex.names" ist kein Grafikparameter
12: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "width" ist kein Grafikparameter
13: In box(...) : "horiz" ist kein Grafikparameter
14: In box(...) : "cex.names" ist kein Grafikparameter
15: In box(...) : "width" ist kein Grafikparameter
16: In title(...) : "horiz" ist kein Grafikparameter
17: In title(...) : "cex.names" ist kein Grafikparameter
18: In title(...) : "width" ist kein Grafikparameter
```

Comment: Do any lines in your input file have strings in them ?  Since your data in the post just contains numbers, `read.table` just interprets them as numbers.

Comment: no, its just numbers. I would like to have them interpreted as strings!

Comment: Since you have no header in the file, I assume that the column name in `dat` is `V1`; have you tried something like `dat$V1 <- as.numeric(dat$V1)` ?

Comment: In case you are wondering, I didn't down vote.

Comment: @steveb had no effect. you meant as.character(dat$V1) i suppose?

Comment: No, `as.numeric`.  Your issue as stated is that the values are already characters.  If so, they need to be converted to numbers to create the bar plot.  Can you include the output of `str(dat)` in your post.  So immediately after you read in the file, what does `str(dat)` show ?  If it contains characters, convert to numeric based on the previous comment.  If there is not error then run `str(dat)` again to confirm the values are numeric.  If they are numeric, you should be able to plot them (or at least you will have a different error).

Comment: Also, you are using invalid parameters in the call to `plot`.  They are being ignored (so warnings and not errors).  That will have to be fixed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to plot this in a bar plot . X-Axis: Occurences Y-Axis: Portnumber

I think you want

```
dat <- scan("data/ports.txt‌​")    ## use `scan` if you are to read in a vector
x <- table(dat)    ## contingency table
barplot(x, col=c("#ccf0fe9f"), horiz=TRUE, cex.names=0.5, las=1, width=5, 
        xlab="Occurences", ylab="Attacks")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!

for whatever reason this didn't work aswell - untill i changed the "" to '' in the scan ():O

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
barplot(table(dat), col=c("#ccf0fe9f"),horiz=TRUE,cex.names=0.5,las=1,width=5, xlab='Attacks')
```

plot() will create a scatter plot as default, so you need to use the barplot() function, and the table() function creates the counts which are required for your bar chart